# How to hide the inherited menu item in odoo menu?

Tags: python, odoo

In my project I have created a module that inherits models and views from HR module (employees), so I have define in the manifest that my module should deoends on the hr module. When I install my module it also installs the hr module and shows the "employees" menu item in odoo main menu. I have no use for the employees views, so how can I hide the "employees" menu item?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the groups allowed to use/access the current menu entry using the `Access Rights` tab of the menu item form view.

Go to `Settings/Technical/User Interface/Menu Items` and search for `Employees`, in the `Access Rights` tab select the ERP manager group or a group with no user to restrict access to everyone.

Menus are regular records in database, usually declared through data files. You can use a data file to update `Employees` menu record using its external id.

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="hr.menu_hr_root">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_erp_manager')])]"/>
</record>
```

*The special command [[(6, 0, ids)]](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L3273) replaces all existing records in the set by the `ids` list*